# Given $A = BAC$ and all matrices are invertible. What do we know about matrices $B$ and $C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I know that the following equation holds

$A = BAC$,

and I also know that all matrices are invertible. Now, the equation is trivially true if $B$ and $C$ are the identity. What other $B$ and $C$ could satisfy the equation?

Comment: You could have, say, $B=A$ and $C=A^{-1}$.

Comment: The set of pairs $(B,C)$ that satisfy this equation is exactly 
$$\lbrace (AP^{-1}A^{-1},P), P \text{ is invertible}\rbrace$$
(For $P=I$, you get your solution, and for $P=A^{-1}$, you get José Carlos Santos' one)

Comment: To put it another way, $C$ could be any invertible matrix whatsoever, and then $B$ would be $AC^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Comment: 1) $B = \lambda I$ and $C = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} I$. 2) $B = A^k$ and $C = A^{-k }$

Comment: As mentioned, $C$ can be any invertible matirx (together with $A$ it determines $B$) , analogue , $B$ can be any invertible matrix (together with $A$ it determines $C$). So the answer to the question is : We know nothing about $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A = B\,A\,C \Leftrightarrow A\,C^{-1} = B\,A \Leftrightarrow A\,C^{-1}\,A^{-1} = B$$

Therefore, for ANY invertible matrices $A$ and $C$, the equation will be true if and only if $B = A\,C^{-1}\,A^{-1}$, which is invertible.

For a fixed known matrix $A$, the matrix $B$ can be considered a function of the matrix $C$, which is defined in the space of invertible matrices: $B(C) = A\,C^{-1}\,A^{-1}$.

---

Alternatively:

$$A = B\,A\,C \Leftrightarrow B^{-1}\,A = A\,C \Leftrightarrow A^{-1}\,B^{-1}\,A = C$$

Therefore, for ANY invertible matrices $A$ and $B$, the equation will be true if and only if $C = A^{-1}\,B^{-1}\,A$, which is invertible.

For a fixed known matrix $A$, the matrix $C$ can be considered a function of the matrix $B$, which is defined in the space of invertible matrices: $C(B) = A^{-1}\,B^{-1}\,A$.